# How to remove a job from slurm accouting

Tags: slurm

I am querying the job history from slurm with sacct, but lately a user sent over 100k jobs as mistake. I just want to delete these entries and keep the others. Is this possible, without deleting directly in the mysql database?

Comment: [scancel](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scancel.html) - take a look at this. You may want to do  `squeue -u myusername` to see all your processes

Answer (score 0):

There is no Slurm tool to delete specific records in the accounting. What you can do is dump the accounting in a flat file, purge the database, then edit the file, and finally reload the accounting back to the database. See the *ARCHIVE FUNCTIONALITY* section of the `sactmgr` [manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html).